# snmpwalk doesn't work with SNMP v3

Tags: linux, snmp

We have a Cisco switch which we have been monitoring using Nagios over snmpv2 for ages. Recently our auditing team forced us to move to snmpv3 on all network devices.

The Cisco engineer came in and configured snmpv3 on the switches but after that snmpwalk stopped working:

When I try snmpwalk I the following error:

```
[root@nagios libexec]# snmpwalk -u snmprouser -A gs1snmmp -a MD5 -X DES -X gs1snmmp -l authPriv 192.168.13.11 -v3 
SNMPv2-SMI::mib-2 = No more variables left in this MIB View (It is past the end of the MIB tree)
```

The above credentials are right as it throws the following error when they are wrong:

```
[root@nagios libexec]# snmpwalk -u snmprouser -A gs11snmp -a MD5 -X DES -X gs1snmmp -l authPriv 192.168.13.11 -v3 
snmpwalk: Authentication failure (incorrect password, community or key)
```

When I try to get uptime:

```
[root@nagios libexec]# snmpwalk -u snmprouser -A gs1snmmp -a MD5 -X DES -X gs1snmmp -l authPriv 192.168.13.11 -v3 1.3.6.1.2.1.1.3.0
DISMAN-EVENT-MIB::sysUpTimeInstance = No more variables left in this MIB View (It is past the end of the MIB tree)
```

Also:

```
[root@nagios ~]# snmpwalk -v3 -u snmprouser -A gs1snmmp -a MD5 -X DES -X gs1snmmp -l authPriv 192.168.13.11 mib-2.interfaces
IF-MIB::interfaces = No more variables left in this MIB View (It is past the end of the MIB tree)
```

Comment: It looks like you are trying to query a tree your *"snmprouser"* is not allowed to access. Did you double-check the ACLs?

Comment: The Cisco engineer showed me using snmpwalk on Windows and it is working fine. Please see the screenshot: http://oi60.tinypic.com/2w2r2ae.jpg

Comment: in your screenshot, you are querying the OID of "1" - which is the SNMP root. Also, a different device is being queried. In general, what snmpwalk for Windows is able to retrieve, snmpwalk for Linux will do too.

Comment: Yes, I have been trying on different devices, but with the same result. How would I query the OID of "1" using snmpwalk on Linux?

Comment: Not that it matters, but I did notice there's an "-X" instead of "-x" before DES, I think that's wrong too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems the issue was indeed with the SNMP configuration on the switch. Another Cisco engineer came in and sorted it out for us. 'Only' wasted 2 weeks of my time thinking it was an issue on the Linux side. :(

Answer (score 0):

Some code I wrote using Linux and Ruby:

```
def snmp_cmd(cmd)
    `#{cmd} -Oq -v3 -u #{@user} -l authpriv -a MD5 \
    -A #{@auth} -x DES -X #{@priv} #{@name} #{@oid}`
end
```

Running it against a Linux host with an oid of '1' yields the entire mib. Not sure why you want to do this because it takes a long time to complete. Your problem may be 'Cisco-centric' as this snippet also works for me on HP switches and Windows hosts (not the oid=1 part).

You might want to narrow your query to a specific item.